# How to make phone numbers displayed through a space

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please, help. 
Why are numbers displayed without a space?
How to make phone numbers displayed through a space?

```
var phoneBook = {};
function re(command) {
  if (command.split(" ")[0] == "ADD") {
    var name = command.split(" ")[1];
    var numb = command.split(" ")[2].split(",");
    if (!phoneBook.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      phoneBook[name] = numb;
      return phoneBook[name];
    } else {
      phoneBook[name] = phoneBook[name].concat(numb);
      return Object.keys(phoneBook) + ": " + phoneBook[name];
    }
  }
  if (command.split(" ")[0] == "SHOW") {
    var book = [];
    for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(phoneBook).length; i++) {
      var key = Object.keys(phoneBook)[i];
      book[i] = [key + ": " + phoneBook[key]];
    }
    return book;
  }
}
re("ADD Ivan 555-10-01,555-10-03");
re("ADD Ivan 555-10-02");
console.info(re("SHOW"));
// ["Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-03, 555-10-02"]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: "Ivan: 555-10-01,555-10-03,555-10-02"

Comment: _"Ivan: 555-10-01,555-10-03,555-10-02"_ this is the output of your current code

Comment: here its ok. you are just getting nested arrays. run `console.info(re("SHOW")[0][0]);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var phoneBook = {};
function re(command) {
  if (command.split(" ")[0] == "ADD") {
    var name = command.split(" ")[1];
    var numb = command.split(" ")[2].split(",");
    if (!phoneBook.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      phoneBook[name] = numb;
      return phoneBook[name];
    } else {
      phoneBook[name] = phoneBook[name].concat(numb).join(', ');
      return Object.keys(phoneBook) + ": " + phoneBook[name];
    }
  }
  if (command.split(" ")[0] == "SHOW") {
    var book = [];
    for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(phoneBook).length; i++) {
      var key = Object.keys(phoneBook)[i];
      book[i] = [key + ": " + phoneBook[key]];
    }
    return book;
  }
}
re("ADD Ivan 555-10-01,555-10-03");
re("ADD Ivan 555-10-02");
console.info(re("SHOW"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected. If you just need the phone numbers printed then get the value of the phone number by accessing it:

```js
var phoneBook = {};
function re(command) {
  if (command.split(" ")[0] == "ADD") {
    var name = command.split(" ")[1];
    var numb = command.split(" ")[2].split(",");
    if (!phoneBook.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      phoneBook[name] = numb;
      return phoneBook[name];
    } else {
      phoneBook[name] = phoneBook[name].concat(numb);
      return Object.keys(phoneBook) + ": " + phoneBook[name];
    }
  }
  if (command.split(" ")[0] == "SHOW") {
    var book = [];
    for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(phoneBook).length; i++) {
      var key = Object.keys(phoneBook)[i];
      book[i] = [key + ": " + phoneBook[key]];
    }
    return book;
  }
}
re("ADD Ivan 555-10-01,555-10-03");
re("ADD Ivan 555-10-02");
//get the full result
console.info(re("SHOW"));
console.info(re("SHOW")[0][0]);
```